# Spring Boot add if statement in every action in controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, controller, boilerplate

I need to redirect every action in the controller depending on some condition from the service.

**Example:**

```
@RestController
public class MyController{

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @GetMapping("/action1")
    public String action1() {
        if(myService.checkIfError()) {
            return "redirect:/error";
        } else {
            // specific code of action1
        }
    }

    @GetMapping("/action2")
    public String action2() {
        if(myService.checkIfError()) {
            return "redirect:/error";
        } else {
            // specific code of action2
        }
    }
}
```

In code above both `action1` and `action2` have some specific code, but part of code `if(myService.checkIfError())return "redirect:/error";}` is same to all actions.

Can someone tell me how to remove this boilerplate code so that code specific to actions remains?

Comment: you can differentiate the implementation by using some query param or path parm. 
Another approach may be u can  just move the error check logic to seperate method and reuse it everywhere.

Comment: Please can you demonstrate first part in an answer?
Error check logic is already set into "checkIfError" function located in service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a **filter** for this:

```
@Component
public class YourFilter implements Filter {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

        if (myService.checkIfError()) {
            httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("/error");
            return;
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }
}
```

Spring Boot will autowire this filter, and it will intercept all requests.

Comment: Is it necessary to autowire this filter into controller or it is done automatically?

Comment: This will be applied to all requests to all controllers; the controller doesn't need to know about it.

Comment: How can I prevent this to be applied to all controllers? I need to apply this filter only to desired controller.